# Is it a good ideal to use loops for Rcpp's NumericMatrix in C++?

Tags: c++, r, rcpp

I want to use `Rcpp::NumericMatrix` as argument type for a C++ function that will loop through it. Should I now copy the whole content of the `Rcpp::NumericMatrix` into a C-style array in order to have good performance or is it also fast to use the []-operator of `Rcpp::NumericMatrix` in a C++-loop many times? Is there a faster way than to use random access in order to loop through a `Rcpp::NumericMatrix` instance?

Comment: Try both and compare?

Comment: It's all discussed in the Rcpp documentation and packages. We even have benchmarks.

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel Thanks! I started today with Rcpp.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since it is a rather laid back day and I wasn't able to quickly find a benchmark for this ([Rcpp Sugar](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/Rcpp/vignettes/Rcpp-sugar.pdf) Section 4 is TBD and Section 6 is TBD)... And my general curiosity... Let's give it a go!

First up, to access a `NumericMatrix`'s *c-style* array we first need to convert a `NumericMatrix` to `std::vector`. From the `std::vector`, we can extract a *c-style* array governed by a pointer. Under this structure, we are making a copy of the data entirely. Nevertheless, we can investigate the question proposed and then some.

Below is a quick test suite of functions that focus on four different components:

1. *c-style* array
2. `std::accumulate`
3. Looping a `std::vector`
4. Element-wise access with `NumericMatrix`

Now, I did "cheat" in the pure *c-style* function as I did not attempt to calculate the size of the array from itself via `sizeof()` calculations. (This would of potential caused a few problems as the pointer size would have been given...)

Let's check out the test suite of functions.

```
#include <Rcpp.h>

// [[Rcpp::export]]
double c_for_access(const Rcpp::NumericMatrix& x){

  // Cast to std vector
  std::vector<double> v = Rcpp::as<std::vector<double> >(x);

  // Convert to c-style pointer
  double* pv = &v[0];

  // Sum using a pointer
  double sum = 0;
  for(unsigned int i = 0; i < v.size(); i++){
    sum += *(pv+i);  
  }

  return sum;
}

// [[Rcpp::export]]
double stl_for_access(const Rcpp::NumericMatrix& x){

  // Cast to std vector
  std::vector<double> v = Rcpp::as<std::vector<double> >(x);

  // Summing Operation
  double sum = 0;
  for(unsigned int i = 0; i < v.size(); i++){
    sum +=  v[i];
  }

  return sum;
}

// [[Rcpp::export]]
double stl_access(const Rcpp::NumericMatrix& x){
  // Cast to STL Vector
  std::vector<double> v = Rcpp::as<std::vector<double> >(x);

  // Use STL to return sum
  return std::accumulate(v.begin(), v.end(), 0.0); // Important to specify 0.0 instead of 0. 
}


// [[Rcpp::export]]
double matrix_access(const Rcpp::NumericMatrix& x) {
  // Define matrix information and looping variables.
  unsigned int r = x.nrow(), c = x.ncol(), i, j;

  // Sum elements
  double sum = 0;
  for(i = 0; i < r; i++){
    for(j = 0; j < c; j++){
      sum += x(i,j);
    }
  }

  return sum;
}
```

Now, let's generate some data:

```
# Set seed for reproducibility
set.seed(1337)

# Create a 100x100 matrix
x = matrix(rnorm(10000),nrow=100,ncol=100)
```

Next, we calculate and check the sum of each object to make sure they are all equal:

```
# Calculate each object
oracle = sum(x)     # Oracle is the correct answer given by R

c.out = c_for_access(x)

stl.loop = stl_for_access(x)

stl.lib = stl_access(x)

rcpp.pure = matrix_access(x)

# Check all equal
all.equal(oracle, c.out)

all.equal(oracle, stl.loop)

all.equal(oracle, stl.lib)

all.equal(oracle, rcpp.pure)
```

Finally, we run a **microbenchmark** on each function:

```
# install.packages("microbenchmark")

microbenchmark::microbenchmark(oracle = sum(x),

               c.out = c_for_access(x),

               stl.loop = stl_for_access(x),

               stl.lib = stl_access(x),

               rcpp.pure = matrix_access(x)
)
```

From the microbenchmark, we have:

```
Unit: microseconds
      expr    min     lq     mean  median      uq    max neval
    oracle  8.105  8.705  9.11406  8.7060  9.0060 24.016   100
     c.out 30.319 31.220 31.75767 31.2210 31.5210 54.636   100
  stl.loop 30.320 30.921 32.56819 31.2210 31.5210 55.836   100
   stl.lib 30.319 30.920 31.64063 31.2205 31.6705 50.133   100
 rcpp.pure  9.907 10.807 10.95122 10.8070 11.1070 12.909   100
```

So, the matrix summation via `Rcpp` is ~2 microseconds slower than R but it is considerably faster than the `std::vector` and *c-style* array setup.

Q.E.D?

Comment: Awesome! So the conversion is a considerable overhead, exactly what I wanted to know.